# Share data using EventEmitter Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

i have 2 component in my angular 2 project.
The first component is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'second-component',
  template: '<div><div>'
})

export class SecondComponent implements OnInit{

@Output() changeDetect = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();

private value: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.value = false;
  this.doSomething();
}

doSomething(): void {
  if (2 > 1) {
    this.value = true;
  }
}

changeDetection() {
  this.changeDetect.emit(this.value);
}

}
```

What i need to do, i need to send `this.value` value in the second component.
For example method `doSomething()` does something to change `this.value`, it might be true or false, whatever.
Second component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'first-component',
  template: '
  <div>FIRST COMPONENT<div>
  <second-component (changeDetect)="changes($event)"></second-component> 
  <span>{{_message}} 
  </span>'
})

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

private _change: boolean;
private _message: string;

ngOnInit() {

}

changes(event) {
  // Here i want to get boolean value from the first component to do something like below
  if (event === true) {
    message = 'true';
  }
}

}
```

I understand my question is pretty noobie but i hope you just understood what i meant.
I'll be happy for any advices, because im totally lost in it.

Comment: are you saying the event is not emitted in to the childComponent?

Comment: What is happening currently? Is the value that is emitted not a bool?

Comment: Also in general, use console.log or the debug tools in the browser to help diagnose any typescript/javascript problems.

Comment: Be careful naming things like `changeDetection`, it will most likely confuse you or someone else down the road as Angular 2+ allows you to inject a `changeDetectorRef` which gives you control over change detection.  This is very different than emitting an event via an `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to emit the value manually

```
doSomething(): void {
  if (2 > 1) {
    this.value = true;
    this.changeDetection();
  }
}
```

Comment: actually that hepled me, but why should i emit the value inside this method?  why it's not working if this method outside ? it's kinda confusing me

Comment: Angular change detection is not something that works automagically as you expect. Your function 'changedetection' is just a function. I suggest your read https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7 first to understand change detection and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your not accessing the property of your emitted value.

```
changes(event) {
  // Here i want to get boolean value from the first component to do something like below
  if (event.value === true) {
    message = 'true';
  }
}
```

When you do:

```
if (event === true)
```

It's the same as:

```
if (event) {
```

You're checking that it's not null/undefined.

Also as Alexander suggests, you have to wire up:

```
changeDetection() {
  this.changeDetect.emit(this.value);
}
```

To an event handler on your front-end/angular code if you haven't already.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that helped me alot, thanks for your response, but i still can't understand why should i put changeDetection() method inside of doSomething() method, why it's not emit if it's outside

Comment: But I don't understand, your changeDetection() function is wired up to an event handler on your front-end right? Can you post your HTML also?